# No he podido obtener datos del wsdl del dane

Tags: soap, postman, wsdl

Estoy intentando obtener datos del wsdl del dane. He revisado como acceder a traves de soap. Cuando ingreso a la direccion http://appweb.dane.gov.co/sipsaWS/SrvSipsaUpraBeanService?wsdl con un get me arroja la siguiente informacion sobre como esta el servicio:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5. -->
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5. -->
<definitions xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://servicios.sipsa.co.gov.dane/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://servicios.sipsa.co.gov.dane/" name="SrvSipsaUpraBeanService">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://servicios.sipsa.co.gov.dane/" schemaLocation="http://appweb.dane.gov.co:80/sipsaWS/SrvSipsaUpraBeanService?xsd=1"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadr">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadr"/>
    </message>
    <message name="consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadrResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadrResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr"/>
    </message>
    <message name="promedioAbasSipsaMesMadrResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:promedioAbasSipsaMesMadrResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="promediosSipsaCiudad">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:promediosSipsaCiudad"/>
    </message>
    <message name="promediosSipsaCiudadResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:promediosSipsaCiudadResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="promediosSipsaMesMadr">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:promediosSipsaMesMadr"/>
    </message>
    <message name="promediosSipsaMesMadrResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:promediosSipsaMesMadrResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="promediosSipsaParcial">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:promediosSipsaParcial"/>
    </message>
    <message name="promediosSipsaParcialResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:promediosSipsaParcialResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="promediosSipsaSemanaMadr">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:promediosSipsaSemanaMadr"/>
    </message>
    <message name="promediosSipsaSemanaMadrResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:promediosSipsaSemanaMadrResponse"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="SrvSipsaUpraService">
        <operation name="consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadr">
            <input message="tns:consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadr"/>
            <output message="tns:consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadrResponse"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr">
            <input message="tns:promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr"/>
            <output message="tns:promedioAbasSipsaMesMadrResponse"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="promediosSipsaCiudad">
            <input message="tns:promediosSipsaCiudad"/>
            <output message="tns:promediosSipsaCiudadResponse"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="promediosSipsaMesMadr">
            <input message="tns:promediosSipsaMesMadr"/>
            <output message="tns:promediosSipsaMesMadrResponse"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="promediosSipsaParcial">
            <input message="tns:promediosSipsaParcial"/>
            <output message="tns:promediosSipsaParcialResponse"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="promediosSipsaSemanaMadr">
            <input message="tns:promediosSipsaSemanaMadr"/>
            <output message="tns:promediosSipsaSemanaMadrResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="SrvSipsaUpraPortBinding" type="tns:SrvSipsaUpraService">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/" style="document"/>
        <operation name="consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadr">
            <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="promedioAbasSipsaMesMadr">
            <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="promediosSipsaCiudad">
            <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="promediosSipsaMesMadr">
            <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="promediosSipsaParcial">
            <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="promediosSipsaSemanaMadr">
            <soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="SrvSipsaUpraBeanService">
        <port name="SrvSipsaUpraPort" binding="tns:SrvSipsaUpraPortBinding">
            <soap12:address location="http://appweb.dane.gov.co:80/sipsaWS/SrvSipsaUpraBeanService"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Pero cuando intento consumir el servicio no me arroja nada. Estoy cometiendo algun error de como la estoy solicitando? No tengo mucho conocimiento de como se debe de consumir este tipo de servicios y ya en algun otro momento lo hice sin ningun inconveniente pero como tal no he podido encontrar mayor documentacion y otra respuesta en la pagina del DANE o en internet. Agradezco mucho el apoyo que se me pueda brindar con este caso.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://servicios.sipsa.co.gov.dane/">
   <soap:Body>
    <consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadr xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
        <codProducto>500</codProducto>
    </consultarInsumosSipsaMesMadr>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Estuve revisando un poco este WS, y es malísima la documentación. En especial la función que tu pones de ejemplo, donde debes cambiar "codProducto" por "arg0". No aparece en ningún lado alguna lista de códigos para consultar, yo probé con números al azar y me retornaba una respuesta vacía. Luego en las otras funciones si tuve retornos, yo use SoapUI para probarlo.

Comment: Como recomendación a parte si vas a ser un software que consuma esto, si es posible hazlo en java. El consumo entre aplicaciones java es sencillo, pero java incumple algunas normas del soap por lo que con otros lenguajes hay que pelear un poco más

Comment: Mil gracias por tu comentario. Hay posibilidad que me compartas el codigo con el cual hiciste el llamado? Porque creo que lo estoy haciendo mal, para mi seria de gran ayuda.

Comment: Hola a todos. ya pude hacerlo sin problemas con la recomendacion de Yussef. Lo monte por postman y seleccion el tipo de aplicacion como application/soap+xml Luego genere el codigo para usar con PHP y todo corrio sin problemas. Mil gracias por el apoyo.